# Django: NoReverseMatch

Tags: django

I get an [image: error] when adding a line to my html template

```
<a href="{% url 'delete' posts.id %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Delete</a>
```

My url:

```
url(r'^delete/(?P<pk>[A-Za-z0-9\w|\W]+)/$', views.DeleteView.as_view(), name='delete'),
```

My view:

```
class DeleteView(deletePostForm, DeleteView):
    template_name = 'delete_confirm.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: When possible, try to copy and paste your error text rather than use an image. Welcome to stack overflow, recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can I ask why you're not just using `(?P<pk>\d+)`?

Comment: You know, you can take a screenshot! More than that you can copy-paste.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
<a href="{% url 'delete' %}{{posts.id}}/" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Delete</a>
```

Since `posts` is available in the template context, access its id. This will generate the proper link and you will receive the `delete` request.